# Are individual atoms affected by gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, atoms

If we could place individual atoms in the vacuum, would it fall towards earth just like a bowling ball in the vacuum?

Comment: Yes, why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Yes. Next question?

Comment: Even the gravitational force on an electron has been observed. Google Fairbanks experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Gravitation holds for all massive objects, no matter how tiny the mass be be.

The only caveat is, the force is directly proportional to the mass, so for an atom-Earth interaction, the force is small due to the small mass of the atom:
$$F_{\rm (Earth-Atom)} = \frac{G M_{\rm (Earth)} m_{\rm (atom)}}{r_{(Atom-EarthCentre)}^2}$$ 
But if you add the stipulation of vacuum, and there is no other force around, this feeble force shall also produce net motion of the atom.

Comment: I find it a little misleading when you say "this feelbe force shall also produce a net motion". In fact the hydrogen atom falls just as fast as a lead weight.

Comment: @MartyGreen - Yes, of course. But when you say "_falls as fast_", you are referring to the acceleration, and the velocity acquired due to it. That acceleration is clearly the same for hydrogen and lead, being $g$. But the force is that same number multiplied by the mass, which is different for the two, or rather, more "feeble" for one as compared to the other.  Nevertheless, what I actually meant in the context was - due to direct proportionality with mass, the force of attraction on an atom is feeble as compared to that on a football. However, as feeble as it may be, any non-zero force ...

Comment: (contd.) shall produce net motion in accordance with the second law. The crucial requirement though is, provided there isn't any other force of a bigger magnitude than this feeble course. In that case also, the net motion is determined by the second law, but the effect of this feeble force would be masked by the more dominant contribution from the other force. (Just to clarify what I meant.) :)